# print/alert array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array in javascript and I want to print/alert it (without change array).
my code is like this:

```
function myFunction() {
var fruits = [{'a':"Banana", 'c':"Orange", 'v':"Apple", 's':"Mango"}];
fruits[0].toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;}
```

can anybody help me please?

Comment: Just use `JSON.stringify(fruits);`

Comment: @Ziki That's `JSON`, not `Json`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara 10X fixed.

Comment: `console.log(fruits)` ??

Comment: here's a fiddle of the above:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/v7kxx3ku/

Comment: @Ziki can you show me it in http://jsfiddle.net plz?

Comment: @Ziki `<p>Click the button to convert the array into a String.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
`

Comment: @WilliamSchroederMcKinley Tnx a lot :)

Comment: @Ziki Tnx. Plz add your answer. it's useful for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.stringify(fruits);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnqL89bn/)